# viewDidAppear equivalente no apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple

Necessito apresentar uma pequena animação (uma sequência de imagens) quando o meu App inicia. O método `willActivate` não me ajuda, pois ele ainda não está mostrando nada. Existe alguma notificação ou algo para poder assegurar que já está mostrando a cena na tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ciclo de vida de `WKInterfaceController` ainda é bastante limitado e só conta com os métodos `-willActivate` e `-didDeactivate`. Logo, se precisas executar algo um pouco depois da chamada do método `-willActivate` não vejo outra maneira a não ser usando `NSTimer` para disparar a animação.

Answer (score 1):

A partir do watchOS 2.0, você pode utilizar o método didAppear, que será chamado logo após os elementos da tela terem sido mostrados.

[WKInterfaceController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/didAppear)